# Mirror broken android to Linux?

Tags: mount, android, screencast, adb

I'm fairly inexperienced with Linux and have a very difficult situation. 
My last cellphone's screen cracked, got water damaged and now has a dead screen. It's a newer phone (Galaxy A8) and it still connects to my PC. The touchscreen also works, it's only the display that's down.

My goal is to somehow mirror it to Linux so that I can unlock the pattern code and recover some photos. 
One potential issue is that usb debugging could be disabled.

I tried installing adb and ran this code:
adb shell screenrecord --output-format=h264 - | ffplay -

Then I received this error:
pipe:: Invalid data found when processing inputKB sq=    0B f=0/0

Worst case scenario - if there's no way to do it on Linux, I could always partition my hard drive and install Windows. (Knock on wood...)

Do you have any ideas or advice? Thank you for your time, I am immensely grateful! :-)

Comment: You have three options, @Tyler Stockdale; data extraction, Android Bridge Debugging, and OTG + a mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Can we assume it is a Samsung 'Galaxy A8 (2018)', and not the earlier model A8?

*I currently use this model, updated to latest Android.*

---

Normal operation for the A8 (2018) would be:

- You unlock Android, using swipe OR entering PIN.
- When connected via USB, you are prompted to 'Accept' or 'Decline' the connection.
- Once connected, you would be able to copy/backup all the phones memory (from Ubuntu).

---

However, if you have no working screen (to navigate user-interface/UI), this will be much harder.

Just connecting (via USB, or USB-OTG) without approving this access will prevent most actions.